# Conductivity variation on Caustic (NaOH) Dilution System

Tags: physical-chemistry, aqueous-solution, conductivity

I am reading the drawing for an automatic caustic dilution system where 50% NaOH is diluted down to 20%.

I was expecting to see a density sensor on the outlet to provide feedback to the dilution pumps for ratio-ing. i.e. To keep the density at 20% and prevent it from moving to say 19% or 21% by adjusting the amount of water.

However, the vendor seems to have used a conductity sensor on the outlet instead. I am skeptical whether the conductivity of NaOH will vary a lot between 19% to 21%. Isn't it already fully ionized?

Thoughts? Will this work?

Comment: Yes 19-21% solutions are fully ionized, but the relative amount of water is different so the conductivity changes.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea about what would be the percent variation in conductivity between say a 19% vs 20% solution?

Comment: Relax as for conductivity measurements allow for quantitative analysis of electrolytes. It will work

Comment: Relax as for conductivity measurements allow for quantitative analysis of electrolytes. It will work

Comment: As conductivity and concentration are linearly related over small regions I'd guess that in going from 19 to 20% the conductivity would increase by a factor of 20/19.